# I have a MongoDB collection with 580+ fields: should I split it up?

Tags: mongodb, database-design

The vast majority of the fields will not need to be indexed and will never be queried (think display ONLY). There are maybe 20-30 fields that need to be queried.

Likewise, the vast majority of the the fields will be for simple field value pairs (not embedded docs).

Finally, there will be some fields that will store embedded docs, but not a lot and the embedded docs will not be large.

I was thinking of maybe breaking up the collection into two collections:

1. A collection with fields that need to be indexed/queried and fields that need to be displayed in larger result sets (really anything more than 1 single document).
2. A collection with: _id, related_id and data (where data is an embedded doc with all the extra data in it). This collection would only ever be accessed when viewing the "detailed" display of the document.

Also, there will be 100s of millions of documents (eventually).

Comment: What version of MongoDB and what storage engine is being used?

Comment: Haven't set it up yet. Still in planning stage. This is more of a best practices question.